# Issue with Tooltip and custom cursor on image-based links

Tags: html, css, image, cursor, tooltip

I have an image on my webpage that I use for various links - you can hover over the buttons on the image and click to go to another page - but when I was first creating the webpage I had issues with getting the links in the right places.

I had entered the image in the CSS, which was where I was having trouble. I got around it by having the image in the HTML instead, and then using the `<map>` and `<area>` functions. Like so:

```
<img src="(my image url)" width="278" height="430" alt="tricorder" usemap="#tricorder">
<map name="tricorder">
<area shape="rect" coords="125,110,235,180" href="/" alt="home" title="home">
<area shape="circle" coords="92,120,9" href="{text:Alpha URL}" alt="link" title="{text:Alpha}">
<area shape="circle" coords="91,140,9" href="{text:Beta URL}" alt="link" title="{text:Beta}">
<area shape="circle" coords="89,160,9" href="{text:Gamma URL}" alt="link" title="{text:Gamma}">
<area shape="circle" coords="88,180,9" href="{text:Delta URL}" alt="link" title="{text:Delta}">
<area shape="circle" coords="83,216,20" href="{text:Library URL}" alt="navi" title="{text:Library}">
```

There's probably an easier way but I'm new to everything and this works perfectly.

The problem now is that I've installed Tooltip and a custom cursor into the CSS. These work fine for the rest of the webpage, but my custom tooltip settings (white text, black background etc) and my custom cursor (no hand when hovering over links) don't work when hovering over the image links.

I can only assume that it's because my image isn't affected by CSS?? or something along those lines.

I'll try to clarify if you need more information, but this is that last little bit to make it perfect, and I'd appreciate if anyone could help..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style.

The issue is probably related to your tooltip configuration and/or your CSS styles.  I used your above code with the following CSS and it rendered correctly.

```
.custom-tooltip, .arrow:after {
    background: black;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
.custom-tooltip {color:white;}
```

And the following JS:

```
$( document ).tooltip({ tooltipClass:"custom-tooltip", 
    position: {my:"left+5 center", at:"right center"} });
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HarmonicApps/LACXC/)